# CSS Send blinking text using Gmail

Tags: css, node.js, google-cloud-functions, gmail

I am trying to send a blinking text via Gmail in a Firebase function written in node.js. The email body in HTML works well when the HTML page is opened on the local disk. However, when the same HTML is sent in the email, the text doesn't blink. Following is my code snippet :

```
<HTML>
   <head>
    <style>  
        .blink_me {
            animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
            }

            @keyframes blinker {
            50% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blink_me">blinking text</div>
  </body>
```

The overall function code is as below :

```
exports.flashMessage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var result;
    const emailBody = getBlinkerHtml();
    
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'Someone <someone@somewhere.com>', 
        to:'xxxx@yyyy,com',
        subject: `Blinking Message Test`,
        html: emailBody,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
        
        if(erro){
 
            // console.log('Error :SE-001 : ',erro)
            result = 'No';
        } else {
            // console.log(`sent ${emailType} email to ${mailOptions.to}`);
            result = 'Yes';
        }
    });
    response.send(`${result}`);
});

function getBlinkerHtml(){
    return `<html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                        .blink_me {
                            animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
                            }

                            @keyframes blinker {
                            50% {
                                opacity: 0;
                            }
                            }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="blink_me">blinking text</div>
                </body>
            </html>`;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the function code as well?

Comment: Function code is added

Comment: I was wondering is it possible to see blinking text in Gmail at all... Have you tried with other email provider? or are you able to create gmail that is blinking with any other way of creation ? At least gmail UI does not have such possibility....

Comment: I found a few links which suggests Thunderbird can do it. I didn't try it. https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-make-flashing-text-for-emails

Comment: This might be matter of software that you are using to read the email. I think for some it will work and for others not. I tested both my gmail and Microsoft Office (application) and it does not shown blinking text. Anyway this is not a matter of cloud function so I am not able help...